# Is there a way to explicitly detatch an implicitly linked DLL?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, dll

This is not for production code, this is for a unit test.

We have a legacy DLL which frees resources on a DLL_PROCESS_DETACH event. We had a crash scenario in the static destruction phase of an executable because the destructor of a static variable was trying to access resources unmapped by the DLL (dangling reference).

I'd like to reproduce this crash scenario in a unit test so I can prove I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get a handle to the module with [`GetModuleHandle(LPCTSTR lpModuleName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199.aspx), and pass that to [`FreeLibrary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152.aspx).

The documentation for `GetModuleHandle()` states:

> The `GetModuleHandle` function returns a handle to a mapped module without incrementing its reference count. However, if this handle is passed to the `FreeLibrary` function, the reference count of the mapped module will be decremented. Therefore, do not pass a handle returned by `GetModuleHandle` to the `FreeLibrary` function. Doing so can cause a DLL module to be unmapped prematurely.

Despite the warning *not* to do so, that sounds like it is exactly what you are looking to do. This should be fairly easy to test in your scenario, to verify that it does what you want.

Comment: I was going to answer my own question with exactly what you answered ;) but I wanted to test it out first. It looks like I'm able to locate my DLL with GetModuleHandle() and FreeLibrary() is returning TRUE... I'm now trying to verify that the DLL is actually unloaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears the DLL is still not unloaded until after my main returns. Which I guess is the OS's prerogative.

Comment: @HansPassant I wish my code crashed when I did that... then I would be on my way to fixing things ;)